# why my react app has re-rendering loop while using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-query

I'm currently working on a code to update the content of a previous post.

Among them, there is a part where I convert the image URLs received from the server into files and store them in state.

However, with this coding approach, I'm experiencing excessive re-renders.

I'm not sure what to do anymore. Initially, there can be multiple URLs, so I used useQueries.
Could that be the problem?

In summary:

During the initial rendering,

- fetch the information of the previous post from the server.
- Store the received information in state.
- Convert the array of image URLs into an array of files.
- Store the converted files in state.

If you have any information to help solve this problem, such as the cause of the excessive re-renders or possible solutions, please let me know.

```
const ShellUpdate: React.FC = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { data } = useGetShells(parseInt(id as string));
  const urls = data?.data.pictures.map((item: { url: string }) => item.url);
  const ImagesDate = useImageUpload(urls);
  const [uploadedImages, setUploadedImages] = useState<File[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ImagesDate[0].status === 'success') {
      const files = ImagesDate.map((queryResult) => queryResult?.data).filter(
        Boolean
      ) as FileWithPath[];
      console.log(files);
      setUploadedImages(files);
    }
  }, []);
}

export const useImageUpload = (
  updateInitalImages: string[]
): QueryObserverResult<FileWithPath>[] => {

  const queryResults = useQueries(
    updateInitalImages.map((imageUrl) => ({
      queryKey: [queryKeys.imageData, imageUrl],
      queryFn: () => getImageFile(imageUrl),
    }))
  );


  return queryResults;
};
```

When I console logged, I noticed excessive re-renders occurring, and the data was not getting stored in setUploadedImages.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `useEffect` dependency array, first you didn't provide it with any variable, which mean the `useEffect` callback function will run one time after the component elements are rendered, which mean you will have an old version of `ImagesDate` (which belong to a stale closure to be more technical), so to fix this you'd think, okay let's pass it in the dependency array:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
  
      if (ImagesDate?.[0]?.status === 'success') {

        const files = ImagesDate
          ?.filter((queryResult) => Boolean(queryResult.data))
          ?.map((queryResult) => queryResult.data)
          ?? [];
  
        //console.log(files);
        setUploadedImages(files as File[]);
      }
  
    }, [ImagesDate]);
```

well that's normally okay, but having objects(arrays or functions too) in the dependency array is very dangerous for the reason of [Referential Equality](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback#so-when-should-i-usememo-and-usecallback), which mean react will do comparison on the dependency array based on `Object.is` which for objects will always return false, because in javascript:

```js
{} === {} // false
Object.is({}, {}) // false
```

so that will cause the `useEffect` callback to run every time the component re-render, you might ask, but I will not trigger re-render?! well, the use of this line

```
        setUploadedImages(files as File[]);
```

will of course trigger the re-render again, which mean you will get an infinite loop of re-renders...

what possible solutions to this?
the simplest solution possible that I suggest is not to have `uploadedImages` as controlled state, instead have it as `derived state` because you can have it's value based on another state, there's no need to have a setter function for that and have to go all the way to setup a side effect to set it, so this should be enough for it:

```
  //  const [uploadedImages, setUploadedImages] = useState<File[]>([]);

  const uploadedImages = ImagesDate
    ?.filter((queryResult) => Boolean(queryResult.data))
    ?.map((queryResult) => queryResult.data)
    ?? [];

  /*
    useEffect(() => {
  
      if (ImagesDate?.[0]?.status === 'success') {

        const files = ImagesDate
          ?.filter((queryResult) => Boolean(queryResult.data))
          ?.map((queryResult) => queryResult.data)
          ?? [];
  
        //console.log(files);
        setUploadedImages(files as File[]);
      }
  
    }, [ImagesDate]);
    */
```

one more point related to `useQueries`, following the [documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQueries), you should pass a `queries` property to `useQueries`

```
export const useImageUpload = (updateInitalImages: string[]) => {

  const queryResults = useQueries(
    {
      queries:
        updateInitalImages.map((imageUrl) => ({
          queryKey: ['convert to image file', imageUrl],
          queryFn: () => {
            console.log('re calling api with', imageUrl);
            return getImageFile(imageUrl)
          },
        }))
    }
  );


  return queryResults;
};
```